# "Attempting to accept the next goal when a new goal is not available"

Tags: ros, action-server, callback, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm trying to perform an action-client/action-server structure using a callback structure.

So it just has to read info from the goal and publish messages on a turtlesim topic.

When I run this node (either before or after I created the client) every time the server receives a Goal I get this:

```
[ INFO] [1501865084.462187784]: Server Created    
[ INFO] [1501865086.638608252]: I'm in goalCB() and I'm receiving a new Goal
[ERROR] [1501865086.638780375]: Attempting to accept the next goal when a new goal is not available
```

This is my code (which btw for now does nothing, I just wanted to see if everything worked)

```
class polygonAction
{
public
:
polygonAction(std::string name) : 
    as(nh_, name, false),
    action_name_(name)
  {

//register the goal and feeback callbacks
as.registerGoalCallback(boost::bind(&polygonAction::goalCB, this));
as.registerPreemptCallback(boost::bind(&polygonAction::preemptCB, this));
ROS_INFO("Server Created");

//Stuff for turtlesim we don't care
[...]

as.start();


}

  ~polygonAction(void)
  {
  }

  void goalCB()
  {
    ROS_INFO("I'm in goalCB() and I'm receiving a new Goal");
    goal_length = as.acceptNewGoal()->length;
    goal_sides = as.acceptNewGoal()->sides;
    ROS_INFO("Received %d sides and %d lenght", goal_sides, goal_length);

  }

  void preemptCB()
  {
    ROS_INFO("%s: Preempted", action_name_.c_str());
    // set the action state to preempted
    as.setPreempted();
  }

  //Stuff for turtlesim we are not interested in 
 [...]

protected:

        

  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  actionlib::SimpleActionServer<es_1::polygonAction> as;
  std::string action_name_;
  int goal_sides, goal_length, sides_count;
  es_1::polygonFeedback feedback_;
  es_1::polygonResult result_;
  ros::Publisher pub;
  ros::Subscriber sub;

    };

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "polygon_action_server");

  polygonAction polygon("polygon");
  
  ros::spin();

  return 0;

}
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268092/%22attempting-to-accept-the-next-goal-when-a-new-goal-is-not-available%22/) by [Canni](https://answers.ros.org/users/31425/canni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-08-04**:
It's better to include only the important information in your question. This question is only about the mechanics of an action server, the turtle-sim or your polygon are not relevant but just a distraction.

**Comment by [Canni](https://answers.ros.org/users/31425/canni/) on 2017-08-04**:
Yeah sorry, but they were only few lines and they had comments above so i just copied and pasted my code

**Comment by [Canni](https://answers.ros.org/users/31425/canni/) on 2017-08-04**:
I modified the code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can only accept a new goal once, but you have two calls of as.acceptNewGoal(). so just call it once to get a pointer to the current goal. You can check the implementation [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/actionlib/html/simple__action__server__imp_8h_source.html#l00182).

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Canni](https://answers.ros.org/users/31425/canni/) on 2017-08-04**:
RIGHT! Thank you so much! Now I'm trying to get my goal in that goalCB but I don't know how to instantiate it ahahah I'm a total noob in ROS so thank you for your advices!

**Comment by [Canni](https://answers.ros.org/users/31425/canni/) on 2017-08-04**:
Ok done! Thank you so much!

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2021-04-14**:
How did you get around this? I just fixed the same error, also being a total noob